# easy and quick Simple form edit please

Tags: html, forms, required-field

The forms which l have here, have required files to be entered before the submit button. All l need it for the top 'title' list to be required='true'. I know how to do it for each and every of the text forms but unsure how to position the code for an options choice list.

Cheers guys.

Please take a look at the jsfiddle l have created for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/New_to_Websites/5A4vS/#run

```
Code:

<script language="javascript">
    var sa_sent_text = 'Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you soon.';

    function sendme() {
        alert(sa_sent_text);
        document.getElementById("name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("message").value = "";
        document.getElementById("subject").value = "";
        document.getElementById("email").value = "";
        return false;
    }
</script>
<div id="sa_contactdiv">
    <form name=sa_htmlform style="margin:0px" onsubmit="return sendme();">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Title:
                    <br>
                    <select name="title" size="1">
                        <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                        <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                        <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                        <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
                        <option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E-mail Address: <span style="color:#D70000">*</span>

                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required="true" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject: <span style="color:#D70000">*</span>

                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required="true" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Message: <span style="color:#D70000">*</span>

                    <br>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="42" rows="9" required="true">         </textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" style="font-weight:bold">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<select name="title" size="1" required aria-required=”true”>
     <option value="">Please Choose</option>
     <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
     <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
     <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
     <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
     <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
     <option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
     <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

If you have an option with a empty value as default, the required attribute works.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5A4vS/4/)

> The required attribute is a boolean attribute. When specified, the user will be required to select a value before submitting the form.
>
> If a select element **has a required attribute specified**, **does not have a multiple attribute specified, and has a display size of 1; and if the value of the first option element in the select element's list of options (if any) is the empty string**, and that option element's parent node is the select element (and not an optgroup element), then that option is the select element's placeholder label option.

Quoted from [http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-select-element.html](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-select-element.html#the-select-element)

Comment: Thank you. However, there is one crucial problem... In Safari it by-passes all of the messages to fill in the forms. If they are blank and you press submit with them all blank and it goes straight away to the thank you message. May be an issue in other browsers, not tried yet. Which browser are you using by chance?

Comment: Works in perfect in my browser. Any suggestions why? Which browser are you using by chance?

Comment: You are correct, Safari doesn't completely support this html5 feature yet (http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation), but all other recent major browsers do. You shouldn't rely on such a client-side validation anyways and always do a server-side (e.g. php) validation as well.

Comment: @ Sebsemillia I wouldn't know how to do a php validation, if it is going to be too complicated please do not worry. However, if it's just going to be a few short lines of code or similar to what l've already got it may be worth while. (I am very new to websites)

Comment: No, I'm afraid you can't just simply do it in a few minutes if you have zero knowledge in PHP. But as long as you are not storing the data in a database, it's not that crucial. But it's definitely worth while to learn PHP basics if you are seriously interested in developing websites.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td>Title:<span style="color:#D70000">*</span>
                    <br>
                    <select name="title" size="1" required="true">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                        <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                        <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                        <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
                        <option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
```